# Vectorizing a conditional involving shorts

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, visual-c++, vectorization

I'm using a compact struct of 2 unsigned shorts indicating a start and end position.
I need to be able to quickly determine if there are any `Range` objects with a length (difference from start to end) past a threshold value.

I'm going to have a huge quantity of objects each with their own `Range` array, so it is not feasible to track which `Range` objects are above the threshold in a list or something.  This code is also going to be run very often (many times a second for each array), so it needs to be efficient.

```
struct Range
{
 unsigned short start;
 unsigned short end;
}
```

I will always have an array of `Range` sized 2^n.  While I would like to abort as soon as I find something over the threshold, I'm pretty sure it'd be faster to simply OR it all together and check at the end... assuming I can vectorize the loop.  Although if I could do an if statement on the chunk of results for each vector, that would be grand.

```
size_t rangecount = 1 << resolution;
Range* ranges = new Range[rangecount];

...

bool result = false;
for (size_t i = 0; i < ranges; ++i)
{
 result |= (range[i].end - range[i].start) > 4;
}
```

Not surprisingly, the auto-vectorizer gives the 1202 error because my data type isn't 32 or 64 bits wide.  I really don't want to double my data size and make each field an unsigned int.  So I'm guessing the auto-vectorizer approach is out for this.

Are there vector instructions that can handle 16 bit variables?  If there are, how could I use them in c++ to vectorize my loop?

Comment: Do you need to store the range values in an array? Why not store them in another data structure that would make this lookup faster?

Comment: _so it is not feasible to track which Range objects are above the threshold in a list or something_.  If all you want to do is determine whether or not you have ranges which break the rule, then track that.  You do not have to track every object to do that.

Comment: How often do you use `end`? Would it be feasible to switch to a `(start,size)` representation instead of `(start,end)`. You would of course then need to calculate `end` every time it's used, but if the relative usage of `end` vs `size` is low, that could still end up being a win...

Comment: I'd recommend giving `Range` a member function `size() const` that returns the size (same for `begin() const` and `end() const`). Then you can easily and safely change between an internal representation that stores the end vs. one that stores the size, depending on which ends up being used more often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wondering if any value is greater than 4?

Yes, there are SIMD instructions for this.  It's unfortunate that the auto-vectorized isn't able to handle this scenario.  Here's a vectorized algorithm:

```
diff_v = end_v - start_v; // _mm_hsub_epi16 
floor_v = max(4_v, diff_v); // _mm_max_epi16 
if (floor_v != 4_v) return true; // wide scalar comparison
```

Use `_mm_sub_epi16` with a structure of arrays or `_mm_hsub_epi16` with an array of structures.

Actually since `start` is stored first in memory, you will be working on `start_v - end_v`, so use `_mm_min_epi16` and a vector of `-4`.

Each SSE3 instruction will perform 8 comparisons at a time.  It will still be fastest to return early instead of looping.  However, unrolling the loop a bit more may buy you additional speed (pass the first set of results into the packed min/max function to combine them).

So you end up with (approximately):

```
most_negative = threshold = _mm_set_epi64(0xFCFCFCFCFCFCFCFC); // vectorized -4

loop:
    a = load from range;
    b = load from range;
    diff = _mm_hsub_epi16(a, b);
    most_negative = _mm_min_epi16(most_negative, diff);

    // unroll by repeating the above four instructions 4 times or so
    if (most_negative != threshold) return true;
repeat loop
```

Comment: For something the auto-vectorizer can't do, that sure seems simple!

Comment: @user173342: Dealing with interleaved arrays with exactly two members is a special case, and one that the auto-vectorizer probably isn't ready for.